# For each of these cells if contains a value add 0.58

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet, where I need to check a range of cells and for each one that contains a value, it adds 0.58 each time and shows the sum of these in another cell

Heres the setup. So C4-F4 need to be checked. For each one that contains a value it adds 0.58 to BD4.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=COUNTA(C4:F4)* 0.58
```

Will give you the value you need to add to BD4

Comment: Wonderful that worked! I needed 0.58 as opposed to 5.8, but that was no issue! Thanks a lot